# Пересчет индекса после удаление строки в таблице

Tags: javascript, html

Задача такая: указана цена на единицу товара, количество единиц, нужно выводить общую стоимость. Также, удалять товар по нажатию на кнопку. Функции по отдельности реализованы, НО. После того, как я удаляю строку, в функции калькуляции получается неправильный индекс. И при клике на кнопку + или - считает не в той строке. Подскажите, где ошибка?
Алгоритм ошибки: удаляем первую строку, нажимаем на кнопки + или - во второй строке, а считается в третьей, а не в текущей.

```js
const table = document.getElementById('cart');
const rowCount = table.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
const price = table.getElementsByClassName('price');
const count = table.getElementsByClassName('current');
const incBtn = table.getElementsByClassName('inc');
const decBtn = table.getElementsByClassName('dec');
const total = table.getElementsByClassName('total');
const removeBtn = table.getElementsByClassName('trash');

function Calculate(price, count, total) {     
    const itemPrice = price.innerHTML.split(/\$|\./)[1];
    const totalPrice = itemPrice * count.innerHTML;
    total.innerHTML = "$" + totalPrice + ".00";
}

for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {   
    decBtn[i].onclick = function () {
        if (count[i].innerHTML > 0) {
            --count[i].innerHTML;
            Calculate(price[i], count[i], total[i]);
        }
    }

    incBtn[i].onclick = function () {
        if (count[i].innerHTML >= 0) {
            ++count[i].innerHTML;
            Calculate(price[i], count[i], total[i]);
        }
    }

    removeBtn[i].onclick = function () {
        this.closest('tr').remove();
    }
}
```

```html
<table id='cart'>
    <tr>        
        <td class="price">$680.00</td>
        <td class="count">
            <div class="countBlock">
                <div class="dec">-</div>
                <div class="current">1</div>
                <div class="inc">+</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="total">$680.00</td>
        <td class="trash"><button>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td class="price">$545.00</td>
        <td class="count">
            <div class="countBlock">
                <div class="dec">-</div>
                <div class="current">2</div>
                <div class="inc">+</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="total">$1090.00</td>
        <td class="trash"><button>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>        
        <td class="price">$430.00</td>
        <td class="count">
            <div class="countBlock">
                <div class="dec">-</div>
                <div class="current">1</div>
                <div class="inc">+</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="total">$430.00</td>
        <td class="trash"><button>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы планируете менять структуру списка, тогда нужно отказаться от использования внешней переменной `i` и кажды раз получать элементы, отталкиваясь от нажатой кнопки. Например, так:

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#cart tr');

function Calculate(price, count, total) {
    const itemPrice = price.innerHTML.split(/\$|\./)[1];
    const totalPrice = itemPrice * count.innerHTML;
    total.innerHTML = "$" + totalPrice + ".00";
}

for (const row of rows) {
    row.querySelector('.dec').onclick = function () {
        const tr = this.closest('tr');
        const count = tr.querySelector('.current');
        if (count.innerHTML > 0) {
            --count.innerHTML;
            Calculate(tr.querySelector('.price'), count, tr.querySelector('.total'));
        }
    };

    row.querySelector('.inc').onclick = function () {
        const tr = this.closest('tr');
        const count = tr.querySelector('.current');
        if (count.innerHTML >= 0) {
            ++count.innerHTML;
            Calculate(tr.querySelector('.price'), count, tr.querySelector('.total'));
        }
    };

    row.querySelector('.trash').onclick = function () {
        this.closest('tr').remove();
    };
}
```

```html
<table id='cart'>
    <tr>        
        <td class="price">$680.00</td>
        <td class="count">
            <div class="countBlock">
                <div class="dec">-</div>
                <div class="current">1</div>
                <div class="inc">+</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="total">$680.00</td>
        <td class="trash"><button>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td class="price">$545.00</td>
        <td class="count">
            <div class="countBlock">
                <div class="dec">-</div>
                <div class="current">2</div>
                <div class="inc">+</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="total">$1090.00</td>
        <td class="trash"><button>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>        
        <td class="price">$430.00</td>
        <td class="count">
            <div class="countBlock">
                <div class="dec">-</div>
                <div class="current">1</div>
                <div class="inc">+</div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="total">$430.00</td>
        <td class="trash"><button>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Учту на будущее!